# c program to display card deck per category using dynamically linked lists

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I am developing a program for university where I want to shuffle a deck of cards, but first I need to declare said deck. For this, I used a dynamically linked list where each node contains a pointer to a char array containing the cards, one array for each category. However, the compiler gave me quite a number of errors, which are:

- Line 15: "initializer element is not constant"
- Line 27: "conflicting types for 'head' " and the same error in line 15
- Lines 29, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 38, 39: "expected '='  ','  ';'  'asm' or 'atribute' before '->' token"
- Line 48: "invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'int')"

```
/*1*/ #include <stdio.h>
/*2*/ #include <stdlib.h>
/*3*/
/*4*/ //declaration of deck
/*5*/ char spades[13][3] = {"AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "TS", "JS", "QS", "KS"};
/*6*/ char hearts[13][3] = {"AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "TH", "JH", "QH", "KH"};
/*7*/ char diamonds[13][3] = {"AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "TD", "JD", "QD", "KD"};
/*8*/ char clubs[13][3] = {"AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "TC", "JC", "QC", "KC"};
/*9*/
/*10*/ //declaration of pointers to each category array
/*11*/ int *ptr_s = spades;
/*12*/ int *ptr_h = hearts;
/*13*/ int *ptr_d = diamonds;
/*14*/ int *ptr_c = clubs;
/*15*/ int pointers[4] = {ptr_s, ptr_h, ptr_d, ptr_c}; //array with pointers to categories
/*16*/
/*17*/ //declaration of individual node for dynamically linked list, where each node is a pointer for each category array
/*18*/typedef struct cards_category
/*19*/    {
/*20*/        int pointer;
/*21*/        struct cards_category *next;
/*22*/    }cards_category_t;
/*23*/
/*24*/ //list creation
/*25*/
/*26*/cards_category_t *head = NULL;
/*27*/head = (cards_category_t *) malloc(sizeof(cards_category_t));
/*28*/ //first node
/*29*/head->pointer = ptr_s;
/*30*/head->next = (cards_category_t *) malloc(sizeof(cards_category_t));
/*31*/ //second
/*32*/head->next-> pointer = ptr_h;
/*33*/head->next->next = (cards_category_t *) malloc(sizeof(cards_category_t));
/*34*/ //third
/*35*/head->next->next-> pointer = ptr_d;
/*36*/head->next->next->next = (cards_category_t *) malloc(sizeof(cards_category_t));
/*37*/ //fourth and last
/*38*/head->next->next->next-> pointer = ptr_c;
/*39*/head->next->next->next->next = NULL; //end of list
/*40*/
/*41*/ //display deck on screen (13 cards/one category per line)
/*42*/void display_deck (pointers)
/*43*/    {
/*44*/        int i;
/*45*/        int array[4];
/*46*/        for (i=0; i<4; i++)
/*47*/            {
/*48*/                printf("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n", *array[i]);
/*49*/            }
/*50*/    }
/*51/
/*52*/int main ()
/*53*/    {
/*54*/        display_deck(pointers);
/*55*/        return 0;
/*56*/    }
```

Please note that for this project I am required to use linked lists only, so there is no other way I can make this. Also, I only started programming this semester, I'm fairly new to it so any detailed explanation of my mistakes would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Do not assign `char` arrays to pointers to `int`s, `char *` and `int *` have different align requirements, all those `int *ptr_x` should be `char (*ptr_x)[3];` (pointer to array of 3 chars)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an enormous amount of problems with your code. First off, never put line numbers as comments: if your editor doesn't have a line number function I suggest getting another. Cleaning that up to get your program to work was a pain in the ass and almost made me not want to help you.

Secondly, you're putting expressions outside of a function. That's simply not how C works: are you perhaps from Python?

Thirdly, you just don't have a grasp on how types work in C. There's so many errors regarding how you assign things from incompatible types that your code is practically a toxic substance that any compiler would die from imbibing. Going through each and every one would require a novel, so I'll just say that you have to massively review how types work in C, and especially pointers because using plain ints as pointers is just no bueno.

With that said, here's the code fixed into something that at least works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char spades[13][3] = {"AS", "2S", "3S", "4S", "5S", "6S", "7S", "8S", "9S", "TS", "JS", "QS", "KS"};
char hearts[13][3] = {"AH", "2H", "3H", "4H", "5H", "6H", "7H", "8H", "9H", "TH", "JH", "QH", "KH"};
char diamonds[13][3] = {"AD", "2D", "3D", "4D", "5D", "6D", "7D", "8D", "9D", "TD", "JD", "QD", "KD"};
char clubs[13][3] = {"AC", "2C", "3C", "4C", "5C", "6C", "7C", "8C", "9C", "TC", "JC", "QC", "KC"};

char *ptr_s = (char*)spades;
char *ptr_h = (char*)hearts;
char *ptr_d = (char*)diamonds;
char *ptr_c = (char*)clubs;
typedef struct cards_category {
    char* pointer;
    struct cards_category *next;
} cards_category_t;

void display_deck(char** pointers) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", pointers[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    char *pointers[4] = {ptr_s, ptr_h, ptr_d, ptr_c}; //array with pointers to categories
    cards_category_t *head = NULL;
    head = (cards_category_t *) malloc(sizeof(cards_category_t));
    head->pointer = ptr_s;
    head->next = (cards_category_t *) malloc(sizeof(cards_category_t));
    head->next->pointer = ptr_h;
    head->next->next = (cards_category_t *) malloc(sizeof(cards_category_t));
    head->next->next->pointer = ptr_d;
    head->next->next->next = (cards_category_t *) malloc(sizeof(cards_category_t));
    head->next->next->next->pointer = ptr_c;
    head->next->next->next->next = NULL;
    display_deck(pointers);
    return 0;
}
```